dracut with btrfs (raid1) on lvm on luks
I’m using Ubuntu with dracut for initramfs with BTFRS on LVM on LUKS:
$ lsblk -o name,type,mountpoint,fstype
NAME              TYPE  MOUNTPOINT                   FSTYPE
sda               disk                               
├─sda1            part  /boot/efi                    vfat
└─sda2            part                               crypto_LUKS
  └─disk_a        crypt                              LVM2_member
    ├─swap_b      lvm   [SWAP]                       swap
    └─root_a      lvm   /                            btrfs
sdb               disk                               
└─sdb1            part                               crypto_LUKS
  └─disk_b        crypt                              LVM2_member
    ├─swap_a      lvm   [SWAP]                       swap
    └─root_b      lvm                                btrfs


If BTRFS is using only the logical volume root_a as single disk, the system is booting without any problems.
If BTRFS is using disk_a and disk_b as RAID1, the system is stuck indefinitely waiting for the root-filesystem (systemd: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-… limit …). On the dracut-shell I see only the first logical volume root_a and not the second one (root_b). After running lvm_scan the second logical volume is found and I can boot the system.
Why ist there at first only one logical volume or how can i tell dracut to scan for lv’s after unlocking the the disk?
EDIT:
/etc/kernel/cmdline:
root=UUID=<uuid>

/etc/kernel/cmdline.dracut:
root=UUID=<uuid> rd.luks.uuid=… rd.luks.name=… rd.luks.key=… rd.luks.options=…

(rd.luks.… for both LUKS-partitions)
I’ve tried adding rd.auto=1 in /etc/kernel/cmdline.dracut, but this doesn’t work.
EDIT 2:
After adding rd.lvm.vg=<vg> rd.lvm.lv=<vg>/root_a rd.lvm.lv=<vg>/root_b to /etc/kernel/cmdline (/etc/kernel/cmdline.dracut doesn’t work) the system does boot. (Yay!)
I still don’t understand why rd.luks… have to be in /etc/kernel/cmdline.dracut and rd.lvm… in /etc/kernel/cmdline and why root_a was found without rd.lvm…/rd.auto.

Show us your kernel arguments (/proc/cmdline). Unless the kernel command line contains rd.auto=1 (off by default), dracut will only activate devices that are explicitly listed using rd.lvm.vg/lv= or rd.luks.uuid=.
